# How to access .env variables from public folder - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, directory, root

I am trying to access the `environment variables` to the `public folder` in my react(CRA) application. I'm not sure if it is possible. I've read the docs in REACT however, my concern is not discussed there. My goal is to setup a dynamic firebase service worker based on the environment. (i.e. dev, test, prod).

on my `firebase.js` file inside the public folder, I tried calling the `process.env.REACT_APP_API` but got undefined. I tried the one on the React docs `%PUBLIC_URL&` still no luck.

this is the content of my `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file inside the public folder.

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-messaging.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Please advise. Thank you

Comment: Can you add your `env.js` file?

Comment: Yeah the env variables will be available during build time, but not during runtime. Your public folder scripts will only be executed during runtime I assume, so no env variables. You could probably add a step to your build process to generate the js file, but there also might be a better way to hook into firebase in a compiled app (e.g., including the firebase script in your normal react bundle)

Comment: I'd be interested in what `firebase.js` looks like and where it's used in your app. I suspect you could indeed have it as a module in your react app that gets bundled like the rest.

Comment: Actually, it is called `firebase-messaging-sw.js`. I believe by default, firebase is looking for this file when generating a token to send to the app server. The said js file could be empty or not, but it is needed to be in the root folder.

Comment: I just edited the body of my question. Thanks Nick for answering.

Comment: @Heisenberg you able to resolve the issue ? Im also looking for a solution

Comment: Sorry but, no. I refactored my code :\

Comment: @Heisenberg - How you refactored it? could you please elaborate ?